# Доставка and/or Поставка

Tags: выбор-слова

Is there any difference between the nouns 'доставка' (delivery) and 'поставка' (delivery)? I mean to ask if a delivery of a package to a residence requires a different noun than a commercial delivery (iron, bulk deliveries of grain, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

Доставка = transportation to the end point, often retail, or letter delivery or cargo or luggage or people. Can include any transportation, not only sale-related. Giving the thing to the addressee or putting at the place of addressee.

Поставка = always wholesale, in big volume, may not include transportation to the end point, just unloading at agreed place. Always sale-related, usually between companies, not to end-user.

In short, доставка = transportation to the end point, поставка = sale in big volume between companies

Answer (score 4):

Доставка = delivery, shipment, shipping.

Поставка = supply.

Answer (score 2):

Both terms are indeed quite alike though definitely different. One can tell that "поставка" is subtly wider term.

"Доставка" is about delivery to the end customer, "поставка" is about the whole logistic cycle: shipment, supply etc. - and it usually implies describing the process en-masse.

"Доставка товаров на дом" is correct, "поставка товаров на дом" is not. 
On the other hand though "наладил доставку лекарств за границу" is acceptable, "наладил поставку лекарств за границу" would sound more appropriate.

To put it simple, "доставка" is more about deliver getting something by a person from  the Amazon, and "поставка" is more about the process of sending wood from the Amazon to some, don't know, wood factory.